# How can I calculate an average turnaround time in weeks/days in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column indication turnaround time expressed in weeks and days as illustrated in the photo.
How can I calculate the average for such a range of cells?

[image: example]

Comment: What would the output be given these inputs? Do you want to answer to be `Average x weeks and n days`? Or do you want the average in days? hours? etc. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes I want the average to be in the same format please n weeks n days

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the new `Spill Over` feature in excel you can do this in a formula

```
=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1:A5,1,SEARCH(" ",A1)))) & " weeks " & AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1:A5,SEARCH("weeks",A1)+6,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH("weeks",A1)+6)-9))) & " days"
```

Comment: It's coming back with a value error.

Comment: So you don’t have spill over feature. You can try confirming with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER which enters the formula as an array formula

Comment: Or, your sample data is not representative of your actual data. I tested against the strings you provided

Comment: Straight forward formula solution +:)

Comment: Oh you also could be getting the error if you are including the header in your formula. You can only input the time values here (so A1:A5 in my formula doesn’t consider a header value)

Answer (score 1):

**A simple array approach via `Split()`**

This approach

- `[1]` assigns range data in days to a 2-dim array `data` ,
- `[2]` calculate the average via WorksheetFunction `Average` based on day values of the data array passed as argument and
- `[3]` display results in **days** *and|or* **weeks + days**

```
Option Explicit                      ' declaration head of code module

Sub RangeAverage()
'[0]Get data
    With Sheet1                       ' ‹‹ change to your project's sheet Code(Name)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        Dim data
        data = .Range("A1:A5").Value
    End With
'[1]Assign day values to 2-dim datafield array
    Dim i As Long, tmp
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        tmp = Split(data(i, 1), " ")
        data(i, 1) = tmp(0) * 7 + tmp(2)
    Next i
'[2]Calculate average
    Dim avg As Double: avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(data)
    Dim weeks As Long: weeks = avg \ 7
'[3]Display in VB Editor's immediate window
'   ~> Average: 31.8 days = 4 weeks 3.8 days
    Debug.Print "Average: " & vbNewLine & _
        avg & " days" & " = " & _
        weeks & " weeks " & avg - weeks * 7 & " days"
End Sub
```

**Addendum** *//Due to @UdearBoy 's comment*

Of course a user defined function might be a more practical vehicle allowing even to choose the form of average display.

Passing a boolean argument `DisplayDaysOnly:= True` expressly would show **days only**, by default you'd get a **weeks and days** result (default setting to False):

```
Function RangeAverage(rng As Range, Optional DisplayDaysOnly = False) As String
'[0]Get data
    Dim data: data = rng.Value
'[1]Assign day values to 2-dim datafield array
    Dim i As Long, tmp
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        tmp = Split(data(i, 1), " ")
        data(i, 1) = tmp(0) * 7 + tmp(2)
    Next i
'[2]Calculate average
    Dim avg As Double: avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(data)
    Dim weeks As Long: weeks = avg \ 7
'[3]return average following optional user argument
    If DisplayDaysOnly Then             ' If True:       ~> Average: 31.8 days
        RangeAverage = avg & " days"
    Else                                ' Default False: ~>   4 weeks 3.8 days
        RangeAverage = weeks & " weeks " & avg - weeks * 7 & " days"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I would go with a UDF that takes a range input and does the same thing over a macro but +1 for array solution

Comment: Thanks for feedback, you are absolutely right. The above procedures just demonstrates the way @urdearboy :-)

Comment: data(i, 1) = tmp(0) * 7 + tmp(2) came back with a bug

Comment: Do you have empty values inside the range? Possibly items with double blanks or days- only inputs? Just debug the item you are referring to via a `Stop` code - @Ayman